# Label on Watu Quiz not aligned with Radio Button

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have created a Watu quiz however the labels are not aligning with the radio buttons. How would I style this and align??

Page here - https://training.thermochamp.com.au/203-2/

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `style.css`, add following:

```css
.quiz-form input[type="checkbox"], 
.quiz-form input[type="radio"] {
  vertical-align: -1.2em !important;
}

/* style more */
.question-content ~ div {
  border-left: 4px solid #666;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding-left: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tqhf0p3m/1/

I couldn't attach the fonts, but you can more or less get some ideas from it.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much @Panwen... This works great. Is there a way to style this more. Say to make it look something like this? https://training.thermochamp.com.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/07/Quiz-Type.png

Comment: Thanks alot @panwen. Is it possible to change the look of the radio button so bigger like the example and different color when selected?

Comment: That will be more difficult than you think. You have to mock one with `span` or `div`. This should help: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp